# The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'fn_dblog', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a user and gave him access to run sp. That sp also has to update a table based on the type of work.

But when the user runs sp, it gives an error:

```
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'fn_dblog', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: fn_dblog is not a procedure. It is a system table function that need some extra privileges

Comment: I said when the user wants to run the sp I wrote, she gets this error!

Comment: That is undocumented function. Apparently it requires more permissions that what you consider - as mentioned [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217584/grant-select-on-function-fn-dump-dblog-in-sql-server-without-granting-sysadmin). Better question is why a "user" would ever need to do this.

Comment: because I found this function used in the trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required permission to use the `fn_dblog` system table-valued function is sysadmin role membership.

Importantly, this function is undocumented so it should not be used in application code, especially to update a table.

**EDIT:**

Your comment indicates the function is used in a trigger. You could create a certificate and certificate user that's a sysadmin role member as described [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) and then sign the trigger with that certificate. That will confer sysadmin permissions to the trigger code and allow non-sysadmin users to use the function but only in the context of the trigger.

I would normally include an example T-SQL script in my answer but I want to strongly discourage you from going down the path of using the undocumented system function in app code.

You have a classic [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) that needs to be solved differently. Ask a new question about how to provide the functionality you need without using `fn_dblog`. Include your existing code in the question.

Comment: how to GRANT select on this function in SQL Server without GRANTing sysadmin?

Comment: @akbari, don't go there. See my updated answer.

Comment: I agree with you that using this function is not correct. But now I have to go the same way to improve the procedure in the future.

I read the link you sent me. I made the certificate, I reached step 4.4.
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON Playtable TO my_first_cert_user

On this issue, what should I do instead of VIEW DEFINITION
I put ?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to resolve this issue

Comment: @akbari, don't grant permissions for your use case. Create a certificate and login in master, add the certificate login to the sysadmin role, copy the cert to your user db, and sign the trigger. The scripts to do this are in various sections of the article but you should focus on section 5, server-level permissions.